# Matplotlib cuts off top of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am not able to achieve the plot I would like. With `plt.margins(0)`, the "top" of the plot is cut off like so:

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.ylabel("RMS value")
plt.xlabel("Interval nr.")
plt.plot(range(len(rms_arr)), rms_arr,marker="o", markersize=4)
plt.title("RMS PLOT")
plt.margins(0)
plt.show()
```

Removing `plt.margins(0)` gives this plot, where the y-axis looks strange at the bottom.

[image]

How can I prevent the top from being cut off? Thanks!

**Update**

With `plt.margins(0, None)`, I got this plot. It looks good on the top, but the bottom is still a bit squashed.
[image]

Comment: Try `plt.margins(0, None)` and see if this produces what you want

Comment: @Sheldore, unfortunately it did not. See the update^

Comment: Try adjusting the axis limits using `plt.ylim(bottom, top)`.

Comment: Try something like `plt.ylim(4.95, 7.3)`. Modify the limits as per your taste

Comment: ylim worked beautifully. Thanks!